# How to add dynamic slugs in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, hosting, web-hosting

I am currently making a URL shortener site where I will be able to shorten links and then get the shortened URL and its unique id stored on the database. To access the shortened URL, I planned to add a slug to the URL making  my URL look like this:

```
mysite.com/randomUrlId
```

But when I add a slug to my page (hosted [here](https://test-shortly-com.stackstaging.com/)), it shows an error. I am very sure this can be done using the `.htaccess` file but I am not sure about how to approach it.

How can we add dynamic slugs?

This is the `.htaccess` file which I got by default:

```
#+PHPVersion
#="php74"
AddHandler x-httpd-php74 .php
#-PHPVersion

#+OptionsIndexing
#="1"
Options +Indexes
IndexOptions +FancyIndexing
#-OptionsIndexing
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do add 3 important things in your question. 1st: Sample of input, 2nd: Sample of output and 3rd: your tried code as your efforts. Please do edit your question with these details and let us know then, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have no idea of how this can be achieved. I had more info if u need on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73258799/how-to-add-url-slugs-when-we-dont-know-the-slug) post which got closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. It was more like a hacky solution but what I did is I added my main `index.html` file to 404 error and now it works perfect. This is the line I added:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
```

In the `index.html` file I then manage the links and if it is found to be incorrect, open the 404 page.